# PhpStorm - autoclose and autocomplete HTML tags without typing "<" at the beginning

Tags: html, ide, phpstorm, editor, jetbrains-ide

So... I used Atom to this date and I wanted to try out PhpStorm and I have an issue with HTML tags.

**How PhpStorm does it:**

If you want to auto complete HTML tag, you have to type for eg. `<d` than autocomplete menu appears, press enter -> it autocompletes `<div` and if you want to close it, you have to type `>` and boom you have `<div><\div>`.

**How Atom does it** (how I want it):

But in Atom you can just type `di` and it shows you that autocomplete menu and if you press enter it automatically autocompletes and autocloses it to `<div></div>`.

**Final question:**

Is it possible to achieve it just like in Atom? Just without the need of typing that `<` at the beginning and `>` at the end of the first tag?

Comment: how about visual code. you just write for example ".container" and press enter and it generates automatic an div with the class "container"

Comment: Well that sounds lit, but I like the other phpstorm features. And I believe that phpstorm has plugin for that, but I just need to google it. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: no problem.. by the way there is an extension in visual code its called "PHP Snippets from PHPStorm" maybe it could help you

Comment: Hmmm... well I'm going to check it out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just type `div` and hit `Tab` - PhpStorm will auto-generate `<div></div>`.
`.container`+ `Tab` will result in `<div class="container"></div>`.

Please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-zen-coding-support.html for more information

Comment: You can type `p.` and hit `tab` as well and it will generate `<p class=></p>`. If you want the `id` type `p#` and `tab`. Super useful.